# What is the syntax for make_unique for a pointer of base type to a derived object?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

Consider the following base and derived classes.

```
class base
{
public:
    int i{9};
    virtual void func()
    {
        cout << "base" << endl;
    }
    virtual ~base()
    {

    }
};

class derived : public base
{
public:
    int i{4};
    void func()
    {
        cout << "derived" << endl;
    }

};
```

I would like to create a `unique_ptr` of `base` type to `derived` object. I know I can do

`std::unique_ptr<base> ptr{new derived};`

but when I do

```
auto ptr = std::make_unique<base>(derived{});
ptr->func();
```

this prints `base`, which is not my intended behavior. What is the correct way to use `std::make_unique` for this case? In addition, why does `auto ptr = std::make_unique<base>(derived{})` do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do

```
auto ptr = std::make_unique<base>(derived{});
```

`make_unique<base>` is going to create a `unique_ptr<base>` which means it is only going to create a `base` object.  Since `derived` is derived from base it is legal to pass that to `base`'s copy constructor so the code compiles, but you have a `base`, not a `derived`.

What you would need is

```
std::unique_ptr<base> ptr = std::make_unique<derived>();
```

to get a `base` pointer that points to a `derived` object.  This isn't the syntax you want, but it works correctly.

If you used

```
auto ptr = std::make_unique<derived>();
```

then `ptr` would be a `std::unique_ptr<derived>`, not a `std::unique_ptr<base>`.

Comment: Ah I see. In `auto ptr = std::make_unique<base>(derived{});` I thought the temporary `derived{}` would be forwarded to the `unique_ptr` constructor. This isn't the case right, otherwise that line would have done what I wanted it to do?

Comment: @roulette01 It is forwarded to the constructor, it just that since you used `std::make_unique<base>`, it is only going to look at `base`'s constructors to make the `base` object. Since `derived` is derived from `base`, it can call `base`'s, `base(const base&)` constructor that the compiler implicitly generated.  This slices the derived object to just the base part.